# How to modify a js file then save it back to a file?

Tags: node.js, module

I like to update a javascript file (module) in node.js then save it. I have the following js module.

```
var test = {
   scripts: ["a.js","b.js"],
   getScripts: function()
   {
        return this.scripts;
   }
}

module.exports = test;
```

I like to load the above module in other modules then update scripts array then save it back to a file. I tried to use **JSON.stringify(test)**, but it doesn't preserve getScripts methods.

Is there a hack or trick for this?

Comment: You better `JSON.stringify` that `scripts` array to a file whenever you feel like this. In your node module, [watch file](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) with serialized array.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much need to read the script in using `readfile`, *textually* manipulate the `scripts` array, and then write it back out using `writefile`.